# select() sometimes blocking for longer than provided timeout

Tags: macos, sockets, bsd

I have a connected TCP socket in non-blocking mode. Sending and receiving data works correctly. Receiving is implemented as a loop on a dedicated thread as such:

```
fd_set fdset;
FD_ZERO(&fdset);
FD_SET(internal->m_socket, &fdset);
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = timeout_ms / 1000;
timeout.tv_usec = (timeout_ms % 1000) * 1000;
int ret = select(internal->m_socket + 1, &fdset, nullptr, nullptr, &timeout);
if (ret == 0) {
  // handle timeout then loop
} else if (ret < 0) {
  // handle error then abort
} else {
  ret = recv(...);  // Read data available on socket then loop
}
```

The TCP connection goes over WiFi from my MacBookPro running OS X 10.11.5. When I turn off WiFi while the connection is established, some follow-up `select()` calls can take quite longer than the specified timeout value.

Here's the proof by adding logging calls (`IN` and `OUT` are printed respectively just before and after `select()` with the passed in timeout value and the actual measured elapsed time):

```
(WiFi is ON, thread is continuously receiving from socket)

08:31:15  -------- IN = 15000
08:31:30  -------- OUT = 14999
08:31:30  -------- IN = 15000
08:31:45  -------- OUT = 15000
08:31:45  -------- IN = 15000
08:32:00  -------- OUT = 15000
08:32:00  -------- IN = 15000
08:32:15  -------- OUT = 15002
08:32:15  -------- IN = 1000
08:32:15  -------- OUT = 87  <--- data received
08:32:15  -------- IN = 4913
08:32:15  -------- OUT = 0  <--- data received
08:32:15  -------- IN = 15000

(WiFi is turned OFF at this point in the middle of a `select()` call)

08:32:30  -------- OUT = 15004  <--- ok
08:32:30  -------- IN = 1000
08:32:31  -------- OUT = 1003  <--- ok
08:32:31  -------- IN = 1000
08:32:32  -------- OUT = 1006  <--- ok
08:32:32  -------- IN = 1000
08:32:43  -------- OUT = 10999  <--- NOT OK: 10X longer
08:32:43  -------- IN = 1000
08:32:48  -------- OUT = 4965  <--- NOT OK: 5X longer

(truncated)
```

Note that there is no obvious pattern: sometimes the bug doesn't seem to happen, but most often it does. It can be the immediate `select()` call following turning off WiFi that takes longer than the specified timeout, or one or more afterwards.

Comment: Your select timeout is only one second? Why?

Comment: There's a lot of code that lives above this snippet and some other logic is running if receive times out. For instance, I use 15s timeout by default, but if the app thinks the connection is not working, it will send a Ping to the server and then reduce the timeout to 1s, wait a few seconds for the Pong, and terminate the connection if not received.

Comment: This could be App Nap. See if the Energy tab of Activity Monitor shows your app as napping at the time the problem happens.

Comment: Ah good point, that might explain why it's hard to reproduce, and I *think* that each time it happened, the app was in the background since I was monitoring things in Xcode in the front.

Comment: This appears related to App Nap indeed! If you make it an answer, I'll accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a thread dedicated to running your select loop. Put the thread in the real-time scheduling class. Here's sample code from Apple to so:

```
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void move_pthread_to_realtime_scheduling_class(pthread_t pthread)
{
    mach_timebase_info_data_t timebase_info;
    mach_timebase_info(&timebase_info);

    const uint64_t NANOS_PER_MSEC = 1000000ULL;
    double clock2abs = ((double)timebase_info.denom / (double)timebase_info.numer) * NANOS_PER_MSEC;

    thread_time_constraint_policy_data_t policy;
    policy.period      = 0;
    policy.computation = (uint32_t)(5 * clock2abs); // 5 ms of work
    policy.constraint  = (uint32_t)(10 * clock2abs);
    policy.preemptible = FALSE;

    int kr = thread_policy_set(pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self()),
                   THREAD_TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY,
                   (thread_policy_t)&policy,
                   THREAD_TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY_COUNT);
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        mach_error("thread_policy_set:", kr);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Read more in [Technical Note TN2169: High Precision Timers in iOS / OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2169/_index.html).

Comment: What would this make any difference? This seems overkilled considering the granularity here is seconds, not microseconds. The docs say "Threads that are in the real time scheduling class get first class treatment. They go to the front of the line whenever they need to run." My MacBookPro has 4 physical cores that are idling when the bug happens. There's no reason I can think of for `select()` to hang for an extra 9 entire seconds because other threads would take priority.

Comment: I don't know if it will make a difference. I think it's worth a try so I posted it. If you tried it and it didn't help, let me know and I'll make another suggestion.